# How to use fasterxml Jackson JSON serialization in Spring 4

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Why doesn't my Spring controller return media type `application/json` when I call it with the following curl:

```
curl -v -i -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:8080/properties-ws/prop/2322
```

I've read all other questions and responses on this subject and none address my specific issue.

I'm using Spring 4, and have a simple Controller and pom.

**Controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/prop/{character}", 
    method=RequestMethod.GET,
    produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody CharData getData(@PathVariable(value="character") int codePoint) {
    CharData chData = null;
    chData = CharPropertiesService.getProperties(codePoint);
    return chData;      
}
```

**POM file with the dependency on Jackson**

I included the fasterxml jackson-databind artifact version 2.3.3

Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.joconner.unicode</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>properties-ws</name>
    <artifactId>properties-ws</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.joconner.unicode</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web MVC Features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The controller returns HTTP response 406 with a message:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Any ideas about where I'm not configuring this properly?

Comment: @Sotirios Thanks for attempting to help. I've included the pom as you requested.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Check that your generated WAR contains the jackson lib.

Comment: Yes, 3 jackson jars are in the war -- binding, core, and annotations. My application context xmls do not include anything but a definition of the controller. Is anything else needed?

Comment: You can show us your context. Typically all you need is to register the default configuration with `mvc:annotations driven. Spring will automatically register the Jackson converter if it finds Jackson on the class path.

Comment: I don't have the mvc:annotations driven tag. I'll check this and update my comment/question soon.

Comment: Sry that was my phone. The `mvc:annotation-driven` element should be in your servlet context to configure the MVC stack.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. My context has nothing in it but a single controller bean and the above annotation, but that was enough to get the JSON representation I was looking for. Unfortunately, I don't really understand why this works, and I'll research this to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Sotirios, I've resolved my issue. I'm not sure why this resolved it, but it did.

I simply put the following in my servlet-context.xml:

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

That's it. That's all it took, and now Spring is returning the JSON representation of object that I expected.

Comment: You should really look into why that resolved your problem... that's a *very* important line of XML.

Comment: From what I've since read on the spring doc site, it enables support for "reading and writing JSON, if Jackson is present on the classpath." -- among other things. I guess I'm still baffled by all the magic performed underneath the covers of Spring.

Comment: No worries, I'm still getting over being baffled by it myself. It looks like you're only reading about things things in the context of your current project. Don't do that. (I did for awhile, and it was a mistake). `<mvc:annotation-driven>` is what "turns on" annotations - it tells Spring to look for any annotations you've written and use them to configure your context. *Without this tag, your annotations do nothing* - you might as well comment them out