# How to use jackson binding with Spring 4 returning json

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm new to Spring and Maven and have been having a difficult time trying to create a web app that will return a simple json string.

I've been following the tutorial from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) and got some pointers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330492/how-to-use-fasterxml-jackson-json-serialization-in-spring-4) but could not get it to work. I then read somewhere that the tutorial will not work with Spring 4.

Here's what I have so far.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jsonDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsonDemo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>jsonDemo</name>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>eap</id>
      <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>eap</id>
      <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
        invoking mvn. -->
      <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
        will need. -->
      <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
        folder. -->
      <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
      <id>openshift</id>
      <build>
        <finalName>jsonDemo</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
              <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

  <display-name>jsonDemo</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!--<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>-->

  <!--<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>-->

</web-app>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.webapp.demo" />
</beans>
```

Demo.java

```
public class Demo {

  private long id;
  private String demo;

  public Demo(long id, String demo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.demo = demo;
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getDemo() {
    return demo;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setDemo(String demo) {
    this.demo = demo;
  }

}
```

DemoController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/demo")
  public Demo demo(Model model) {
    return new Demo(1, "Demo");
  }

}
```

To test this in STS, I right-click the project then choose Run As -> Run on Server -> Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0. It opens a browser with url http://localhost:8080/jsonDemo. It gives the HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available. Then I change it to http://localhost:8080/demo but I still get the 404 error. I've also tried http://localhost:8080/jsonDemo/demo but same error.

Appreciate any help.

**UPDATE 1**
Modified web.xml to remove context-param and listener.

**UPDATE 2**
Modified web.xml again and added version=3.0.

**UPDATE 3**
Thanks to JB Nizet, I got it working by changing the annotation of DemoController from @Controller to @RestController.

Also I could not get it to work in the Pivotal tc server configured in Spring Tools Suite so I had to download Wildfly 8.2.0.Final and deployed the war file there to test it.

Comment: The way your `web.xml` is structured, the configuration in `rest-servlet.xml` will be loaded twice - once due to `<servlet>...</servlet>` and again due to `<context-param>...</context-param>`.  Delete `<context-param>...</context-param>` and `<listener>...</listener>`.  Then try accessing `http://localhost:8080/jsonDemo/demo`.  If that doesn't work either, share the Tomcat logs using [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) or as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Here's the latest [log](http://pastebin.com/bymWUEAe). After making changes to the web.xml as suggested, I deleted all the log files then re-ran the project. Still getting 404 though.

Comment: Additional note. I made another change in the web.xml and added "version="3.0"" then re-ran the project. I am getting a different error now. `HTTP Status 500 - Circular view path [demo]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/jsonDemo/demo] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)`

Comment: EIther annotate the class with RestController istead of Controller, or annotate the method with ResponseBody

Comment: @JB is correct.  Since you have annotated your controller class with `@Controller` and not annotated the controller method with `@ResponseBody`, returning `Demo` would cause a callback to `/demo`, hence the error.  Adding `@ResponseBody` to the controller method (or changing `@Controller` to `@RestController`) will ensure that what you return from the method would get serialized to the response body.

Comment: @JB Nizet It seems to be working now. Thank you. If you can post your comment as an answer, I gladly accept it. Also, one other thing I noticed is that it doesn't work when I run it directly from STS. I had to download Wildfly 8.2.0.Final then did an mvn package of the project. Copied the war file to Wildfly's deployments folder. Started Wildfly then accessed the url http://localhost:8080/jsonDemo/demo. Not sure why it doesn't work from the Pivotal tc server configured in STS.